# Observable stops emitting when nested error handler calls onExceptionResumeNext

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

In the following code, I have a nested observable. The sendMessage in the flatMap calls the sendMessage function which is also an observable. If an exception occurs in this nested observable, the onExceptionResumeNext is suppose to catch the exception, process the exception and then continue on as though nothing happened. The exception does get caught but once the processing on the exception completes, no further emissions are made in the stream. Not even the doOnComplete is called. In essence, the onExceptionResume next just hangs.

I have tried onErrorReturnItem but have the same result. I have not found a single example in Stackoverflow or elsewhere for that matter that even shows onExceptionResumeNext or onErrorResumeNext or onErrorReturnItem inside a nested observable and after a day of working on it, I suspect that it may not be possible to support a nested error handler.

NOTE: In the onExceptionResumeNext I am currently just returning

```
Observable.empty<MessageToSend>()
```

In my actual code, I have code to process the exception and I tried returning an observable as well as just returning the data. Doesn't matter what I do - it always hangs.

```
fun postMessages() {
    val msgToSendPublisher = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(MessageToSend())

    msgToSendPublisher
        .flatMap { _ ->
            App.context.repository.getMessageToSend().toObservable()
        }
        .doOnError { error ->
            if (error is EmptyResultSetException)
                App.context.repository.setSendStatusToNotSendingForAllMessages()
        }
        .doOnNext { messageToSend ->
            App.context.repository.updateMessage(messageToSend)
        }
        .flatMap { messageToSend ->
            App.context.repository.sendMessage(messageToSend)
        }
        .doOnNext { messageToSend ->
            messageToSend.dateSent = Date()
            App.context.repository.updateDateLastMessageSent(messageToSend)
        }
        .doOnNext { messageToSend ->
            if (messageToSend.totalMessagesToSend == 1)
                App.context.repository.updateSendStatus(messageToSend, MessageSendStates.NOT_SENDING)
            else
                Observable.just(messageToSend)
        }
        .doOnNext {
            msgToSendPublisher.onNext(it)
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { messageToSend ->

            },
            { ex ->
                onMessagesSent()
            },
            {
                onMessagesSent()
            }
        )
}


fun sendMessage(messageToSend: MessageToSend): Observable<MessageToSend> {
    val obs = Observable.fromCallable {
            if (messageToSend.totalMessagesToSend == 3)
                throw Exception("Couldn't send to recipient.")

            messageToSend
        }.map {
            storeMessageSent(messageToSend)
        }.onExceptionResumeNext {
            Observable.empty<MessageToSend>() // Hangs here.
        ).doOnComplete {
            addNewMessageIfRequired(messageToSend, newMessage)
        }

        return obs
}
```

UPDATE:

I decided to test out a sample code I found that uses onExceptionResumeNext. It looks like this:

```
    Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
        .doOnNext {
            if (it == 2) {
                throw (RuntimeException("Exception on 2"))
            }
        }
        .onExceptionResumeNext(
            Observable.just(10)
        )
        .subscribe(
            {
                var x = it
            },
            {
                var x = it
            },
            {
                var x = 0
                x++
            }
        )
```

If you put a breakpoint on the line inside of the onExceptionResumeNext, it will get called every single time you run the observable for the first time and not just when the exception is thrown. This is clearly a behavior that is not identified in the RxJava documentation. Any developer will be under the impression that it will only get called when an exception is thrown. In the example above, setting the value to 10 is not really an issue. It's effectively just setting up the return value for the case when an exception occurs. However, if this was more elaborate code that stores stuff in the database (which my app does), it will get called when the observable is initialized - which is really bad. In spite of this discovery, it still does not solve my problem in that no further items are emitted. What I did discover in the sample code is that when onExceptionResumeNext is called, the onComplete is also called. Too bad the documentation doesn't mention that either.

Comment: Where did you put those `onErrorResumeNext`? I don't see it in the code provided. Put it on the inner source which can fail and not into the main sequence.

Comment: I'm using onExceptionResumeNext, so the code above doesn't show onErrorResumeNext. But as mentioned, it doesn't matter - the problem still occurs if I use onErrorResumeNext. The main stream and nested stream need their own error handling. I'm just not entirely convinced that this is possible. Also keep in mind that it is entirely possible to use a third party library that contains a nested observable, so it should be possible to support nested error handling.

Comment: I think you run into one of the ambiguities of Kotlin again. You see, in`onExceptionResumeNext { }`, the curly braces create an `ObservableSource.subscribe(Observer)` body that does nothing and is hidden from you as `it` is optional. Replace the curly braces with regular braces and see if that helps for `onExceptionResumeNext`.

Comment: Replacing the curly braces with rounded braces results in onExceptionResumeNext being called all the time. My assumption is that the rounded braces force a call on the method whereas the curly braces provide an anonymous callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `defer` to defer execution of function calls that result in side-effects upon call:

```
Observable<Integer> createFallback() {
    System.out.println("Why is this executing now?!");
    return Observable.empty();
}

Observable.<Integer>error(new Exception())
.onExceptionResumeNext(createFallback())
.subscribe();
```

The `createFallback` runs because you specified it to run by invoking it. If the sequence is rewritten, it should become more apparent why:

```
Observable<Integer> fallback = createFallback();

Observable.<Integer>error(new Exception())
.onExceptionResumeNext(fallback)
.subscribe();
```

Now if you comment out the error-observable part, does it still execute `createFallback()`? Yes and RxJava is not even involved at that point yet.

If you want the side-effects to not happen to `createFallback` this way, you have to defer the execution of the entire method, there is an operator for that purpose: `defer`:

```
Observable.<Integer>error(new Exception())
.onExceptionResumeNext(Observable.defer(() -> createFallback()))
.subscribe();
```

I presume this looks something like this in Kotlin:

```
Observable.error(new Exception())
.onExceptionResumeNext(Observable.defer { createFallback() })
.subscribe()
```

Comment: That helped. Thank you.

Comment: It should be pointed out that although your solution solves the problem with onExceptionResumeNext hanging the code, the other problem I noted about onExceptionResumeNext terminating the stream is still there. the onComplete will still get called. This is bad since the impression is that the stream would normally continue on as though nothing happened. That apparently is not true.

Comment: Please provide the code you have problems with without leaving out important parts. The best would be to have an unit test that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: .onExceptionResumeNext { observer ->
                Observable.just(messageToSend).subscribe(observer)
            }
This works without the defer. Kind of what I was looking for.